# Error al escribir en la base el resultado de un select combinado

Tags: base-de-datos, select2

tengo el clásico combo select en el que elijo la provincia desde la base de datos y le muestra los municipios de esa provincia. Eso funciona bien, pero luego al guardar ese dato en la base de datos siempre escribe el mismo municipio, escoja lo que escoja, el municipio que guarda siempre es Melilla. La estructura que utilizo es codeigniter, por favor ¡qué alguien me eche un cable!

La estructura de la tabla MUNICIPIOS
1   idMunicipio smallint(6)
2   id_provincia    smallint(6)
3   codMunicipio    int(11)
4   DC  int(11)
5   Municipio   varchar(100)    utf8_general_ci
6   cod_INE varchar(5)  utf8_general_ci

y la de provincias es:

```
1   id_provincia smallint(6)        
2   idCCAA  tinyint(4)      
3   provincia   varchar(30) utf8_general_ci
```

id_provincia es la que enlaza ambas tablas.

---

Os copio los códigos.
PRIMER SELECT que funciona bien y lo guarda bien en la base de datos:

```html
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="field-2" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Provincia</label>
                        
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                                                

                          <select name="id_provincia" class="form-control select2"  onchange="show_municipios(this.value)"  style="float:left;" id="id_provincia" data-message-required="<?php echo get_phrase('value_required');?>">
                              <option value="">Selecciona la provincia</option>
                            <?php 
                                $provincias = $this->db->get('provincias')->result_array();
                                foreach($provincias as $rown):
                            ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $rown['id_provincia'];?>"><?php echo $rown['provincia'];?></option>
                                <?php 
                                endforeach;
                                ?>
                          </select> 
                          </div> 
</div>
```

Segundo SELECT ¡el que nos da el error!

```html
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="field-2" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Localidad</label>
                        
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    
<?php                   $provinciass    =   $this->crud_model->get_provincias(); 
                                foreach($provinciass as $rown): ?>
                                
                        <select name="<?php if($id_provincia == $rown['id_provincia'])echo 'idMunicipio';else echo 'temp';?>" 
                                      id="idMunicipio_<?php echo $rown['id_provincia'];?>"
                                          style="display:<?php if($id_provincia == $rown['id_provincia'])echo 'block';else echo 'none';?>;" class="form-control"  style="float:left;">
                                          
                            
                              <?php $tipo = $this->crud_model->get_municipio_by_provincia($rown['id_provincia']); 
                                    foreach($tipo as $row2): ?>
                             <option value="<?php echo $row2['idMunicipio'];?>"><?php echo $row2['Municipio'];?></option> 
                                    <?php endforeach;?>
                            </select>
                            <?php endforeach;?>
                            <select name="temp" id="idMunicipio_0" 
                              style="display:<?php if(isset($idMunicipio) && $idMunicipio >0)echo 'none';else echo 'block';?>;" class="form-control" style="float:left;">
                                    <option value="">Selecciona primero la provincia</option>
                            </select>
                            
                        

     
                            
                        </div> 
                    </div>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_municipios(id_provincia)
  {
      for(i=0;i<=100;i++)
      {
          try
          {
              document.getElementById('idMunicipio_'+i).style.display = 'none' ;
              document.getElementById('idMunicipio_'+i).setAttribute("Municipio" , "temp");
          }
          catch(err){}
      }
      document.getElementById('idMunicipio_'+id_provincia).style.display = 'block' ;
      document.getElementById('idMunicipio_'+id_provincia).setAttribute("Municipio" , "idMunicipio");
  }

</script>
```

En el crud_model.php tengo las siguientes funciones:

```
        /// Provincias y municipios/////

function get_provincias() {
    $query = $this->db->get('provincias');
    return $query->result_array();
}

function get_municipio_by_provincia($id_provincia) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('MUNICIPIOS', array('id_provincia' => $id_provincia));
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

}

En el fichero que escribe en la base de datos los valores tengo:

```
$data['direccion_addr']      = trim($this->input->post('direccion_addr'));
$idMunicipio      = $this->input->post('idMunicipio');
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT Municipio FROM MUNICIPIOS WHERE idMunicipio=$idMunicipio");
foreach($query->result_array() as $muni) {echo $muni->Municipio;}
$data['direccion_city']      = $muni['Municipio'];
$id_provincia      = $this->input->post('id_provincia');
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT provincia FROM provincias WHERE id_provincia=$id_provincia");
foreach($query->result_array() as $provin) {echo $provin->provincia;}
$data['direccion_prov']      = $provin['provincia'];
```